# How to add a drawing function to KineticJS Image

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to create a function in Kinetic JS Image to redraw the image. I am trying to create a warp / curve effect and I need to redraw the image.

My approach is slicing the image and moving each slice of the image on the Y coordinate based on the equation of a circle.

I cannot get the context of the image to redraw it. This is what I got:

```
     warp: function(wx, wy){
        var width = this.getWidth(),
        height = this.getHeight(),           
        context = this.getContext(),
        image = this.getImage();

        for(var n=0; n < width; n++){           
            var sx = n,
                sy = 0,
                sWidth = 1,
                sHeight = height,
                dx = 1,
                dy = 200 * Math.cos(n * 2 * Math.PI / width);
            console.log(dy);
            context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, width, height);
        }           
    }
```

Please give me any suggestions you may have on how to achieve the redraw.
Thanks!